# Getting text from first sibling of given element

Tags: jquery

This jQuery like selector "cheerio" tries to get the text "milk" from the html. but fails. '$' is the cheerio object.
 How can it be done? Thanks

```
<!-- food -->
<tr>
  <td class="label" valign="top" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">
    drinking:&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </td>
  <td class="displayValue" valign="top">
    milk
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$('*').contents().filter(function () {
  if (this.nodeType == 8) {           //found the comments node / title

    // this produced both the texts 'drinking' and 'milk'
    console.log($(this).next().text());  

  }
});
```

Comment: not familiar with cheerio, but there's a tag for it. why not use that?

Comment: P.S: As a general rule of thumb, try to be more specific than "did not work"

Comment: try `$('.displayValue').contents().filter(function () {
  if (this.nodeType == 8) {           //found the comments node / title
    console.log(this.next().text());  //did not work
    console.log(this.next().html());  //did not work
  }
});`

Comment: @guradio there are few hundreds of the posted html and nested every where in a page, the example I posted is just a minimum. Your suggestion references `this` which is is not a node type 8. How will it work? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may be helpful for you.:

```
$('*').contents().filter(function () {
  if (this.nodeType == 8) {           //found the comments node / title
    console.log($(this.nextSibling).text());  //did work
  }
});
```

For some reason, not obvious to me, `$(this).next();` don't work properly. So, I used the native JS `nextSibling`;

Comment: Okey ! here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/1Lu4e8mo/ I'm using chrome !

Comment: this worked for me `console.log($(this).next().children().last().text());`

Comment: Nice ! this code `this.nextSibling.wholeText.trim().replace(/\s/g, '')` produces  `drinking:milk`. I've tested it manually under IE10, Edge, Chrome and Firefox !